# Failed to start ngnix.service: Unit ngnix.service not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, terminal, ubuntu-20.04

I have installed ngnix on ubuntu 20.04 . But when i am giving command `sudo systemctl start ngnix` . I am facing an error

> [Failed to start ngnix.service: Unit ngnix.service not found.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vR3Bz.png)

Please help me out through this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called `nginx`, not `ngnix`. So you need to start it as `sudo systemctl start nginx` (note the spelling).

Comment: thank you sir! my problem is solved... it was silly mistake by me